# When expanding a function in a sphere, why is the complex conjugate of the spherical harmonic function used to calculate the coefficients?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

When expanding a function on a sphere $f(r,\theta, \phi)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-n}^{n}=A_{jnm}j_{n}(\lambda_{n,j}r)Y_{n,m}(\theta,\phi)$. Since what I'm asking involves the coefficients, I'll define them as well.
$A_{jnm}=\frac{2}{a^3J_{n+1}^{2}(\alpha_{n+1/2,j})}\int_0^a\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi f(r,\theta,\phi)j_n(\lambda_{n,j}r)\overline{Y}_{n,m}(\theta,\phi)r^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi dr$

$\overline{Y}_{n,m}(\theta,\phi)=\sqrt{\frac{(2n+1)(n-m)!}{4\pi(n+m)!}}P^m_n(cos(\theta))e^{-im\phi}$

Why is $\overline{Y}$ necessary/convenient/used as opposed to $Y$? If you know or have vague ideas but don't want to tell me hints about things I already thought about like $\overline{Y}=(-1)^mY_{n,-m}$ are slightly better than down voting and not saying anything.

Comment: The only place where the complex conjugation matters is in the azimuthal part $e^{im\theta}$ in $Y_{nm}$. But there it's crucial, since $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i m\theta}\overline{e^{im'\theta}}\,d\phi=2\pi\delta_{m,m'}$ and if one didn't have the complex conjugation then this wouldn't work out properly.

Comment: You may be on to something. In polar coordinates, it wasn't defined as a conjugate and I was thinking the difference could be because it was absorbed into the coefficient of $\sin & \cos(m\theta)$ I think you hit on the answer though. If $m\ne m'$, the integral=0, by the orthogonality of exponentials. When m=m', the integral is exactly $\2pi$, Which normalizes the integral. I'm satisfied now, Thanks! I wish the author would put these things in.

Comment: Okay. Since that's satisfactory, I've added it as an answer.

Comment: You should probably read up a bit on inner product spaces, specially complex ones, in a textbook on linear algebra!

Comment: Exactly. I have a suspicion that the complex version of an inner product space will have the $proj_uv= \frac{\int\overline{u}v}{\int \overline{u}u}u
$ in some form of mathematical mumbo jumbo. I've got plenty of interesting books to look for the answer now that I know the reason isn't related to the conditions of the PDE, just wasn't thinking in terms of the normalization.

Comment: Don t suspect: go grab a linear agebra book!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the only place where complex conjugation can possibly matter is in $e^{im\theta}$, the azimuthal part of $Y_{n,m}.$ But there it's crucial: $Y_{n,m}$ should be orthogonal to any other spherical harmonics, and if one didn't use complex-conjugation this wouldn't have since one would not have $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{im\phi}e^{-im'\phi}=2\pi\delta_{m,m'}$.